# Funciones dentro de iterador for

Tags: r, bucle-for, dataframe

buen dia. 
Intento implementar el siguiente iterador:

```
for (i in c('NIÑA','NIÑO', "Participantes","Protagonistas")) {
  V$i <- replace_na(V$i,0)
}
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: `i`. 
2: Unknown or uninitialised column: `i`. 
3: Unknown or uninitialised column: `i`. 
4: Unknown or uninitialised column: `i`.
```

El df "V" si tiene las columnas c('NIÑA','NIÑO', "Participantes","Protagonistas").
Pienso que estoy usando mal el iterador for.
¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

No, no estas usan mal el bucle, en todo caso lo que está mal es el acceso a cada columna, la función `$` requiere indicar la columna, y técnicamente lo que estás indicando con `V$i` es la columna `i` que seguramente no existe, ten en cuenta que la variable `i` es un vector con los nombres de columna, pero no las columnas. Para hacer lo que intentas, necesitas la función `[]`, la que si puede recibir una cadena con un nombre:

```
for (i in c('NIÑA','NIÑO', "Participantes","Protagonistas")) {
  V[,i] <- replace_na(V[,i],0)
}
```